# How to get a list of all of my entities mapped tables?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In short:  how do I get a list of all the of the table names that are mapped to my entities?

Why:
We have a set of WCF web services backed by NHibernate mapped via FluentNHibernate.  We built a simple yet powerful health checking capabilities into our architecture.  We can call a secured Diagnose() service operation, and it asks our Windsor container for all registered instances of our IHealthCheck interface.  We have a number of concrete implementations of this interface that check the state of our product's installation - i.e. database connectivity, seed data, down string service connectivity, etc. etc.

We've build a number of things that check the health of our NHibernate code.  For example we borrowed this [1] code form Ayende to query each mapping.  I would like to build a check around our custom KeyGenerator implementation that we're using with NHibernate.  We have a table that stores a row per table in our database.  Our HILO algorithm uses that table to perform it's key generation.  So, I would like to write a check that confirms that every mapped entity in our SessionFactory has a row in that table that represents the entities backing table.

Any pointers would be appreciated.  session.SessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata() smells promising, but I can't see to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Cheers.

[1] http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/08/09/NHibernateMappingCreatingSanityChecks.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I've done the same thing by keeping a reference to the NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration I use to build the SessionFactory with.

It has a ClassMappings collection which contains a PersistentClass object for each entity.  The PersistentClass.Table.Name property should be what you're looking for.

Comment: exactly, don't forget the PersistentClass.Table.Schema as well